# Next Js call external API fetch not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am trying to call fetch, but it's giving me an error as "TypeError: Failed to fetch". To fix this, I am now using Axios. but, Somewhere I read that fetch is poly-filled, and no need to use Axios. can anyone suggest any way with a fetch to work?

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (myProfile) callAPI(true);
        else callAPI(false);
    }, [myProfile]);

const callAPI = async (isMyProfile) => {
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://abcd.com/api/user_profile/v1/mine`,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                method: "GET",
            }
        );
       const data = await response.json();
       setData(data);
    };
```

The above call API function was not working with fetch so I used Axios as below and it was working fine then. but what's wrong with fetch?

```
const callAPI = async (isMyProfile) => {
        axios
            .get(`https://abcd.com/api/user_profile/v1/mine`)
            .then((response) => {
                setData(response.data);
            });
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried not passing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header like you're doing with `axios`?

Comment: yes i have tried that too, but not woking

Comment: I have been having the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73495878/internal-next-js-api-call-returns-500-error

The most bizarre thing is that my colleague has cloned my branch from Git, and their fetch calls are working just fine! At this point I have nuked the local version of the repo and started completely from scratch, and that still didn't work. I have no idea why its not working on my machine