# Internal Next.js API call returns 500 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, fetch-api, http-status-code-500

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why an internal API call (Next.js) that I am making keeps returning the dreaded 500 error. The goal here is to make a call to the internal API (Next.js) and then make a call to a Flask server in the backend to retrieve some data (documentation).

From what I can tell, the call in `pages/documentation.js` does not execute any request within `api/documentation.js`. I have logging setup within the Flask server to annotate any requests that are made.

In the frontend, I am seeing `Unhandled Runtime Error - SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.`. And when inspecting the console I see `500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:3000/api/documentation` && `Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.`

I am stuck at the moment. Not sure what else I can google to look deeper into this issue. My lack of web development experience is biting me here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
/* pages/documentation.js */

 // State Variables
 const [documentation, setDocumentation] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!documentation) {
      fetchDocumentation();
    }
  }, []);  

  // API Call to fetch documentation
  async function fetchDocumentation() {
    const fetchResponse = await fetch('/api/documentation', {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    if (!fetchResponse.ok) {
      setDocumentation(await fetchResponse.text());
    } else {
      setDocumentation(await fetchResponse.json());
    }
  };
```

```js
/* api/documentation.js */

import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import getConfig from 'next/config'

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
const BACKEND_API_URL = publicRuntimeConfig.BACKEND_API_URL;

export default async function documentationHandler(req, res) {  
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    let reqURL = BACKEND_API_URL + '/api/documentation';

    const backendResponse = await fetch(reqURL, {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    if (!backendResponse.ok) {
      return res.status(backendResponse.status).send(await backendResponse.text());
    } else {
      const resp = await backendResponse.json();
      res.status(200).send(resp);
    }
  } else {
    res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
  }
}
```

Comment: What do the logs for your backend service say about the error?

Comment: 500, if your errors are coded properly, suggests an issue with the server. Is your backend running properly? Can you hit it with postman or in a browser?

Comment: Inside of the VSCode Terminal I am using to start the front end I see `error - TypeError: fetch failed`. As for the backend, no logs statements are created at the time the frontend tries to make the request. I have manually verified that the Flask server is working by using Postman to make the GET request I am showing in the snippet.

Comment: You should do a similar check in your frontend code. Don't just blindly trust that a `fetch()` request was successful

Comment: I was not able to pull any more information out of the `fetch()` request in the frontend.

Comment: So what happens now? Do you get any different errors? What does your debugging show? You could even just add some simple logging to help find the problem. Use your browser dev-tools to inspect the requests and their actual responses

Comment: If your Flask server isn't getting hit, the issue is most likely in your Next.js API route (`/pages/api/documentation.js`). Do you see any error in the terminal where you started Next.js dev server? Does `BACKEND_API_URL` have the expected value?

Comment: @juliomalves I agree, the issue is definitely within `pages/api/documentation.js`, BACKEND_API_URL has the correct value. The only thing I see in the terminal is `error - TypeError: fetch failed`

Comment: Have you tried removing `mode: 'cors'` from the fetch request in the API route? The request is made from the server-side, it won't be affected by CORS.